# Strange tables in oracle xe

Tags: oracle, docker

I installed docker and pulled wnameless/oracle-xe-11g container.
WWhen I opend it with sql developer I saw many tables with $, what is it?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

These are called dynamic performance tables. Please read below for more info.

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/A57673_01/DOC/server/doc/A48506/dynperf.htm

Comment: It would be visible when you logged on as SYS user . You make your own schema and then get rid of these tables.

Comment: @Raj_Te, I wouldn't suggest "getting rid of these tables" since they're part of the Oracle database system....

Comment: @JeffreyKemp..Agreed with you. But sometime for new users it becomes messy to have so many table which they dont need. So i suggested just create your own schema and view all the table which you like. :-)